# D3.js tooltip position combined with css overflow

Tags: css, d3.js

I'm experiencing problem with displaying tooltips in D3 when combined with the css overflow. Are there any known solutions for this?

CSS code:

```
#chart1 {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
   max-width: 800px;
   max-height: 225px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 140px;
   top: 10px;
}
```

D3 code:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                        .duration(400)
                        .style("opacity", 0);
                    tooltip.transition()
                        .duration(100) 
                        .style("visibility", "visible") 
                        .style("opacity", .8);
                    tooltip.html(d.visitCountry + "<br/> " + tooltipDate(d.startDate) + " - " + tooltipDate(d.endDate) + "<br/> " + d.visitPurpose)
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 15) + 'px') // problem here?
                        .style("top",  (d3.event.pageY - 10) + 'px'); // problem here?
                }) 
                .on("mousemove", function(d) {
                    return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX - 110)+"px");
                })
                .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                    .duration(0)
                    .style("visibility", "hidden");
                });
```

When the page hasn't been scrolled, the tooltip works fine. But the tooltip positions become off otherwise.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/00fhtuyg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried using d3.tip.js?
I think it is easy for doing the tooltip:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/mcvs6vsL/)

API: https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/blob/master/docs/positioning-tooltips.md#tipdirection

Changing the direction programatically

```
tip.direction(function(d) {
  if(d == 'california') return 'w'
  if(d == 'new york') return 'e'
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take into account the overflow-x of the chart. Use the scrollLeft property of the chart1 element to position the tooltip:

```
d3.event.pageX + document.getElementById("chart1").scrollLeft
```

I also suggest using the offsetTop and offsetLeft values instead of hard-coding the absolute offset of the chart div. This will allow you to change the position of the div without having to modify the corresponding js code.

```
d3.event.pageX + document.getElementById("chart1").scrollLeft - document.getElementById("chart1").offsetLeft
```

So you'll have:

```
.on("mousemove", function(d) {
    return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - document.getElementById("chart1").offsetTop + 15)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX-document.getElementById("chart1").offsetLeft + document.getElementById("chart1").scrollLeft + 10)+"px");
})
```

Comment: i've tried the code and it works, except for a word wrap that happens on some tooltips, rendering some of the text unreadable. but thanks for the help!