# tooltip position in d3.js stops working well when there is a scroll in the window

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have seen a lot of examples in which with:

```
.on('mouseover',function(d,i){   
    div.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", ((d3.event.pageY - 28 ))+ "px");
```

they manage to locate a div in the exact position of the cursor. this in my case works well. but when I move the scroll of my page down, this stops working. but if I return the scroll to the original position, it works again. How can i fix it?
this is my piece of code:

```
circles.on('mouseover',function(d,i){   
    div.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", ((d3.event.pageY - 28 ))+ "px");
    div.style("display","block");
})
```

CSS:

```
div.tooltip {   
 position: absolute;            
 text-align: center;            
 width: 60px;                   
 height: 28px;                  
 padding: 2px;              
 font: 12px sans-serif;     
 background: lightsteelblue;    
 border: 0px;       
 border-radius: 8px;            
 pointer-events: none;          
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the CSS for that div.

Comment: You should also consider the offsetTop value of the container(which scroll) in this case.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado done...

Comment: @Gilsha how? How can I do that? I'm not sure what you mean. the scroll is the entire page, not a container.

Comment: Refer the second answer at this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740397/d3-js-tooltip-position-combined-with-css-overflow

Comment: @Gilsha interesting, but as I say, the scroll is not from a specific container, it is from the whole window

Comment: Another possible solutions would be  1) To use the cx and cy attributes of circles instead of mouse position. 2) Try using d3.mouse(this) or d3.event.x, d3.event.y

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when searching for a similar problem. I was able to correct for this problem by using [window.pageYOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset).

So replace

```
d3.event.pageY
```

by

```
d3.event.pageY + window.pageYOffset
```

and the offset should be corrected.